# Make date picker inclusive on max date

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to use an Android date picker to select a date range via two inputs. The start date has the end date as its max date and the end date has the start date as the min date.

I want to allow the date pickers to be set to the same date, to enable selecting a single day as the range (since the range is inclusive).

But it seems that min date is inclusive and max date is always exclusive? Is there any way at all to enable the max date to be inclusive? Right now the date picker styles the end date as if it were selectable, but it's not (which I really hate because that's confusing as hell). It ends up looking like this (to allow Feb 28 as the max *selectable* date -- note how Mar 1 *looks* like it's selectable, but it's not):

[image: Appearance]

I'm not doing anything special in my code. Just creating a `DatePickerDialog` and then calling `dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDateInMs)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize that both minday and maxday are inclusive

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
    }
};

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, myCalendar
        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis()+ DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

datePickerDialog.show();
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and visually, I see the same thing (as the original question asked), but I cannot select the upper bound. It's styled as selectable, but it just can't be. I wonder if it's possibly my phone, as it's stuck on some 5.x version of Android.

Comment: @Kat what is your phone? I test on simulator nexus and it work fine. please try test on some simulator

Comment: I tried an emulator and it indeed looks like something with my phone. That's just weird and now I'm not sure how to handle that, haha. I guess I'll just assume most people's phones aren't as messed up as mine :P.